# IFrame Inside IFrame

Tags: javascript

I am developing a retail store website and am using an html page with JavaScript.   I want to use iFrames.    The main page (Page1) is made up of a banner, a menu on the top and an iFrame below.   For clarity I will call this iFrame1.    In iFrame1 I have an html page (Page2) that contains another iFrame.   I will call this iFrame2.
Page 1 has a top level menu detailing departments for example curtains, cushions, clothes etc.   Selecting one of these items brings up another page (Page2) with a 2nd level menu based upon the selection within the first menu and a ListView of relevant sub headings and images pulled from the database.   Making a selection from the menu in Page2 will change the “Where~ clause in the Select SQL statement and bring up different items for example types of curtains, colours of cushions, sizes available etc.
What I am looking for is a way to automatically resize both iFrames depending on the number of items that are displayed in the ListView in Page2.

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly familiar with iframe's (except for all the people telling me not to use them). So might i suggest using ajax instead with div's? (please correct me if im wrong in suggesting this)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a scrollbar to appear instead of trying to automatically resize an iframe. What you're describing sounds messy though, and iframes there are many reasons why not to use iframes (http://blondish.net/iframes-why-not-to-use-them/). Try divs, and dynamically including the content?